# Need help in normalizing a table upto 3NF?

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

I want to normalize the table 
So far i have done this:

is it my 3Nf correct?

```
Order(orderNo,orderDate,customerId)

Customer(customerId,customerName,customerCurrentAddress,customerPermanentAddress)

Product(productId,productName,Qty,categoryId)

Category(categoryId,categoryName)

Sub-Category(subCatId,subCatName,categoryId)
```

Given table here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F7cQjjxz9rnY6RHaGtZXuwVGFEHBVgNo/view

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--you may find mistakes that make your question unnecessary & we don't know exactly what algorithm you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your textbook. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Hi. Your comment is nowhere near what my first comment said to give. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: I already told you "Your image was not obviously a relational table--a set of distinct rows of one entry per column--so you need to tell us how to interpret it." So telling us that it is an unnormalized table--even if we knew what you meant by either of those two words--does not help us read it. PS ["1NF" has no single meaning.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097) Nor does "unnormalized" or "UNF" or "0NF" or for that matter "relation". "Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook [etc]"

Comment: I don't think you're quite there yet. `Qty` on `Product` looks wrong to me - I don't know what "quantity" that represents - quantity-ordered, or quantity-on-hand, or quantity-in-warehouse, or something else? I would expect a `ProductInventory` table with `ProductId`, `OnHandQty`, `OutstandingPurchaseOrderQty`, `QtyInTransit`, etc. I would also expect there to be an `OrderedProduct` table with columns `OrderNo, ProductId, OrderedQty`. And even the above isn't right, as `OutstandingPurchaseOrderQty` shouldn't be there - just ref the PO's. And `QtyOnHand` is derived from warehouse locations. Etc.

Comment: Don't use links or images for tables or text. Use text to put your table into your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a junction table between Order and Product in order to keep track of orders that contain more than one product.

```
Order(orderNo,orderDate,customerId)

Order_Details(orderNo,productId,Qty)

Customer(customerId,customerName,customerCurrentAddress,customerPermanentAddress)

Product(productId,productName,Qty,categoryId)

Category(categoryId,categoryName)

Sub-Category(subCatId,subCatName,categoryId)
```

Base on the definition from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form): a table is in 2NF if it is in 1NF and **no non-prime attribute is dependent on any proper subset of any candidate key of the table**. Most of your tables only have 2 columns, so they satisfied this. For `Customer(customerId,customerName,customerCurrentAddress,customerPermanentAddress)`, the candidate key is `customerId`, and the other columns completely depend on the whole candidate key, then it's OK.

For 3NF, [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) said: **all the attributes in a table are determined only by the candidate keys of that table and not by any non-prime attributes**. As you see, your tables are all satisfied.